# replace all variables in a $-formatted string in bash

Tags: bash, variables

I have some variables in a bash script. The variables comes from an other script.

I have an other variable containing a string some $names within.
How can I replace all of the variables-like names with the real values of the variables in this string? (I don't know all of the possible variables names)

Example:

```
#From an other place, they are imported by source <( ....)
abc="FOO"
rst="BAR"
format_base='xyz $abc $rst'

# How To Process formate_base?
????

#The Expected Result
echo "$format_base_processed"
#Should Output: xyz FOO BAR
```

Comment: `eval`? Or use a function instead of a variable?

Comment: can you modify `format_base` to be in double-quotes (or) it can't be done (do you have control over it)

Comment: If you're in such a situation, then either you have a very complicated problem and you shouldn't use Bash, or your design is bad. Without any further information about the problem you're trying to solve, we can't give you any good solution, since a good answer would also address your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it would be sufficient to use double quotes instead of single quotes. If the variables exist at the time of reading a double quoted string, there is no problem:

```
abc="FOO"
rst="BAR"
format_base="xyz $abc $rst"
```

If (for some very complicated reason) you have to specify `format_base` before the used variables, you can use things like `eval` or `bash -c`:

```
format_base='xyz $abc $rst'
# "load" variables $abc and $rst
format_base_processed=$(eval echo "\"$format_base\"")
```

Note that the above command has security issues, especially if `$format_base` is not specified by you. Example:

```
format_base='$(injectedCommand)'
format_base_processed=$(eval echo "\"$format_base\"")
```

Here we will execute `echo "$(injectedCommand)"` where `injectedCommand` could be anything, for example `rm -rf *` (do not try this at home).

Comment: yes, it is complicated, because the format_base is defined outside. I think the eval will solve my problem.

Comment: 1. In your second snippet, you probably mean `format_base='xyz $abc $rst'` (with single quotes), otherwise the use of `eval` is useless. 2. Note that using `eval` in this context is dangerous. What if `format_base` contains a semi-colon? what happens with `format_base='xyz $abc $rst; ls'`? Aren't you glad I only use `ls` and not an evil command?

Comment: Just like @gniourf_gniourf said, in the 2nd snippet, it should be: `format_base='"xyz $abc $rst"'`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you for pointing out the wrong quotes. Copy paste is a dangerous thing :).